# HQL throws exception when adding an OR statement

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, hql

I have the following HQL:

```
select r from Route r where r.startingStop.description = 'Railway Station'
```

Now, I have modified my HQL to:

```
select r from Route r where r.startingStop.description = 'Railway Station' or r.destinationStop.description = 'Railway Station'
```

And I get the following exception:

```
org.hibernate.exception.DataException: Subquery returns more than 1 row
```

I have researched on Stackoverflow about this exception but I still could not solve my issue. Thanks in advance.

My fields (Unidirectional mapping):

```
@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = "starting_stop")
private BusStop startingStop;

@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = "destination_stop")
private BusStop destinationStop;
```

Comment: Do you use it as a subquery or is this the whole query?

Comment: I doubt that this query is the one throwing that exception. Post the full stack trace and the relevant code (i.e. the code that causes this exception to be thrown).

Comment: This is the full query

Comment: If u want only single result to be returned from the DB, then use `LIMIT 1` just like `select r from Route r where r.startingStop.description = 'Railway Station' or r.destinationStop.description = 'Railway Station' LIMIT 1`

Comment: Firstly, no I don't want a single result. Secodnly, LIMIT was never supported by HQL

Comment: The error is bcoz your `startingStop` & `destinationStop` is a collection of different elements. So to do *query working you can join the the required tables, create aliases for them & them add condition to evaluate the result.*

Comment: Are these `startingStop` & `destinationStop` are embedded entities or are mapped as join columns ?

Comment: These are embedded entities. Uni-directional Many to One.

Comment: Why you do not use `criteria`?

Comment: I must use HQL over criteria, this is one of the requirements

Comment: R u sure about the mapping between these tables are correct, tables contain the right data ? Bocz, I also have unidirectional relationship in my tables & it's returning data in the form of list. R u trying to get `query.uniqueResult()` from this query ?

Comment: Nope, I am trying to get a list of results. I don't want to limit one one result

Answer (score 0):

As long as we can't know your desired selection or output, here some tips, that will guide to you to solve the issue.

**Cause**: The outer query must use one of the keywords `ANY`, `ALL`, `IN`, or `NOT IN` to specify values to compare because **the subquery returned more than one row**.

**Action**: Use `ANY`, `ALL`, `IN`, or `NOT IN` to specify which values to compare or reword the query so only one row is retrieved.

**Suggestion**: Try to add and `rownum=1` to your subquery conditions if you **DO NOT** care about the value from the list or DO sure that they are the same.

Answer (score 0):

The query works fine but the problem is that it returns more than 1 row. You try to use the result as 1 object but with the **or** clause it returns more than one and throws exception. 
If you use it as a subquery for example and you say:

Something = (your query) it will fail because your query returns 2 results.

If you try to map it to a single object it will also be a problem because you get more than 1 results.